# Failed to start Login Service on BBB after modify /etc/passwd

Tags: beagleboneblack

I'm using Beagle Bone Black board, linux.
While doing some work, I have changed root password to use password while log in to root.
(By default, its root passwd was disabled so could log in root without passwd)
I was trying to disable root passwd again, so want to use default mode without passwd.
I have modified /etc/passwd file and saved and exited, then power off/on.
I tried to log in but log in service has failed so cannot access my BBB.

What I modified is "/etc/passwd" file

```
origianl was "root:x:0:0:............."
modifed is   "root:0:0:..............."
```

I removed "x:" part, BBB forum said it'll solve my problem so I did it.
After then I exited ssh and tried to connect BBB via ssh again but couldn't, refused.
So I reboot my BBB and tried to access via ssh but connection refused continuously.
I connected uart to BBB and monitors log prints from BBB and found that login service couldn't start.

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Login Service.
See 'systemctl status systemd-logind.service' for details.
```

I could log in via debian/temppwd via uart after abort auto login.

I tried to change /etc/passwd but couldn't because I'm not "root".
Even though I tried "sudo", it says "sudo: unknown user : root"
I tried "systemctl status systemd-logind.service" with "debian" account but it didn't work
It says "Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory".
My BBB systemd info is 
+++
debian@beaglebone:~$ ls /etc/systemd
journald.conf  logind.conf  network  resolved.conf  system  system.conf  timesyncd.conf  user  user.conf
+++

How can I recover my problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found s solution and it works for me.

"sudo -u #0 vi /etc/passwd"

from "https://aslamlatheef.blogspot.com/2015/09/why-cant-i-sudo-unknown-user-root.html"